# Interpolating coordinates for a specific time

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate values for X and Y coordinates across time. I am getting NaN's when i try to interpolate for a specific coordinate (X,Y value).

```
data_to_be_interpolated = final_plot_matrix(:,[1 24:25]);
data_to_be_interpolated(isnan(data_to_be_interpolated)) = 0;
X_coordinate = data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,2);
Y_coordinate = data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,3);
time         = data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,1);
coordinates_together = [X_coordinate Y_coordinate];
missing_part = fillmissing(data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,2:3),'linear','SamplePoints',data_to_be_interpolated(2:end,1))
```

The picture of the matix data to be interpolated is shown below [image]

When i give value 5.6366e+04 (time value) to get the interpolated value for X and Y coordinates, now am getting [0, 0], instead of the X and Y value. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to remove the nans from your data first

Comment: interpolating between `NaN`s will always result in `NaN` in output. You have to exclude the `NaN` from your input `X` and `Y`. Also make sure the value `x_new` at which you want the interpolation is contained in your original `X` domain, if not you have to use the `extrapolation` switch of the function `interp1`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, i removed the nans and performed the operation, now its showing [0, 0] instead of nans

Comment: @Hoki, Can you give me little bit more clear pic. I am sorry i am not able to understand what you mean by extrapolation switch.

Comment: Gives us a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Z = fillmissing(X_coordinate,'linear','SamplePoints',time);
```

This will interpolate the missing values.

Remember to convert all zeros to `NaN`.

```
zt = 1:1:5;
za = [100 50 0 0 20];
za(za == 0) = NaN;

zb = fillmissing(za,'linear','SamplePoints',zt);
```

zb =

100    50    40    30    20

Comment: this gives me a null vector. Its not interpolating the missing value

Comment: You need to convert the zeros to NaN.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what in was looking for. I made the edits in the code above.

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing. I want to put  interpolated values for all the columns from column 2 to the end. I wrote a loop to perform this action, it doesnot seems to work. Can you provide some insights to this. Modified code is added above.

Comment: I didn't understand your question properly. When you are using 'fillmissing' the missing values will be automatically replaced by interpolation.

Comment: its solved now. But can i ask you an another question. What if i have multiple columns and i have to do it for all columns? I tried something with for loop, it doensot seems to help much

Comment: See your other question. I put an answer over there. Hopefully that will work for you.